# DirectionalViewPager and PageTransformer create NullpointerException

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-viewpager, fragment

I am using the [DirectionalViewPager](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-DirectionalViewPager/) with Fragments and it works fine, but as soon as I add a page transformation effect via setPageTransformer I get a NullPointerException at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.getChildDrawingOrder. The PageTransformer is tested and works fine with a normal ViewPager. Does anyone know what causes this exception and how to fix it?